# Connect to Facebook Event Search via Google App Engine and restfb

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I want to try Facebook Event search by using restfb - see http://restfb.com . My app resides on google app engine. Unfortunately I am not able to figure out what methods I need to call and how to get the right token (accessToken), which is needed for authentication and for the query.

Here is my snippet:

```
    ScopeBuilder scopeBuilder = new ScopeBuilder();
    scopeBuilder.addPermission(UserDataPermissions.USER_STATUS);
    scopeBuilder.addPermission(UserDataPermissions.USER_ABOUT_ME);
    String accessToken = ""; // How to get?
    FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken, Version.LATEST);
    Page page = facebookClient.fetchObject("cocacola", Page.class);
    System.out.println("Page likes: " + page.getLikes());
```

Comment: Your snippet gets the like count for a specific page - what does that have to do with “Facebook Event search”? And what exactly do you even mean by the latter? Graph API offers only very limited search functionality, which you can find described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#search

Comment: Thanks CBroe. You are right, that my example has nothing to do with events. Anyway, for both use cases (Events or Page likes) I need to authorize and need to know how to get an access token. 

Afterwards I need to figure out how to use the API. Summing up, I guess my example is appropriate to get a little bit further in finding a solution for both issues.

Comment: User access tokens are created by sending the user trough the login flow, so you might want to start there: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/